# Block Camera, shutdown option and keep GPS and mobile data enabled - android

Tags: android, gps, android-camera, android-gps

I got a small project. Company will provide android phones to their employees and company do not want them to access camera and shut down their phone and also they should not be able to disable GPS or Mobile data.

I'm new to android development. Would you please tell me if this is possible. Few reference on how to do that (If possible) :).

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This is such a broad ask... You really should learn about android. Not knowing is no excuse for not reading about android. Should start at the https://developer.android.com/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will stop them from shutting down their phones.  If nothing else they can always remove the battery.

Some of the other stuff can be done via Device Owner permissions and android's device policy manager, which is made for enterprise control of devices.

Comment: This is assuming the battery is removable. That is not true for all android devices.

Comment: With a screwdriver they're all removable.  Or just let them run out of juice and never plug them in.

Comment: Some are actually.. soldered to the board, as noted by the Droid Turbo.. I'm not sure you can remove it. As for the device being forced shutdown via the shutdown dialog, that is what they are trying to block. You can't handle the condition when the battery dies, its finite. Unsure if you can block the shutdown dialog.. even WITH device admin.

Comment: Similarly, nothing stops the user from blocking GPS and mobile data, by putting the device in a suitable container. There is a whole family of "faraday bag" products for this, probably with varying levels of actual results.

Comment: You lack imagination.  But if you prefer-  drop it in a bucket of water and then claim ignorance when it doesn't work.

Comment: Well..Lets forget about shutting down the phone. But is it possible to completely block camera and other media applications?